# Как написать программу в c++, которая будет работать, как клавиатура в старых телефонах?

Tags: c++, строки, map

В старых моделях телефонов, чтобы написать символ, приходилось нажимать кнопку несколько раз. Например, чтобы получить A, вам нужно было нажать кнопку 2 один раз, а для получения Z - кнопку 9 четыре раза.
Таким образом, например, слово GET означало нажатие клавиш 4338.

Так вот вопрос, как написать программу, которая превратит любое слово в такую ​​последовательность чисел?
Я пробовал использовать

```
map<string, string> keyboard = {
            {"a","2"},
            {"b","22"},
            {"c","222"},
            {"d","3"},
            {"e","33"},
            {"f","333"},
            {"g","4"},
            {"h","44"},
            {"i","444"},
            {"j","5"},
            {"k","55"},
            {"l","555"},
            {"m","6"},
            {"n","66"},
            {"o","666"},
            {"p","7"},
            {"q","77"},
            {"r","777"},
            {"s","7777"},
            {"t","8"},
            {"u","88"},
            {"v","888"},
            {"w","9"},
            {"x","99"},
            {"y","999"},
            {"z","9999"}
    };
```

Comment: "О'Кей, Google, как работать с std::map?"

Comment: А символ `o` вы вводить не собираетесь? :)

Comment: вам надо делить входной текст на подстроки, признаком-разделителем должен быть таймаут.

Comment: А в `map<string, char> keyboard` поменять местами ключ и значение, тогда введённый символ получится, как `keyboard[substring]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем просто, если можно сложно...

```
string press(const string s)
{
    const char * press_[] =
    {
        "2","22","222","3","33","333","4","44","444",
        "5","55","555","6","66","666","7","77","777","7777",
        "8","88","888","9","99","999","9999"
    };
    string res;
    for(char c: s)
    {
        int idx = toupper(c)-'A';
        if (idx < 0 || idx > 25) continue;  // Обработка неверного символа
        res += press_[idx];
    }
    return res;
}
```

И никаких `map`.

Только вот как вы планируете отличить, что это было - `GET` или `GDDT`? :) Ведь вы не планируете ставить пробелы, судя по вашему вопросу.

Я к тому, что, наверное, надо все же написать

```
res += press_[idx]; res += " ";
```

Словом, добавлять пробелы в выходную строку.

P.S. Если бы не "выбросы" в четыре семерки и девятки, было бы проще обойтись даже без массива...